# How to activate Nyakuza Metro Preorder Bonus?

Tags: a-hat-in-time

I have pre-ordered the [Nyakuza Metro DLC](https://store.steampowered.com/app/940220/A_Hat_in_Time__Nyakuza_Metro__Online_Party/?curator_clanid=5211581) which it just released today, it should contain a Pre-order bonus which says I own it but it is not installed according to my Steam library.

How do I activate/install it?

[image: Pre order bonus]

Comment: You should just need to tick that box. Check if there is anything paused on your Steam Downloads.

Comment: Nothing happens, I checked it and unchecked it

Comment: Can you try that check for files in the game properties windo?

Comment: Still no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

So apparently they released it just an hour ago.

Comment: Time for mew crimes!

Answer (score 1):

Probably they just forgot to publish it right away or something else is just happening, since I didn't get it aswell even though the DLC is out. The thing is that the pre-order bonus is just a wallpaper, so it might be steam's problem with handling something like that but since I never had a game where it came bundled with wallpapers so

Answer (score 0):

Mine's not checked, but it's downloaded in the following directory:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\HatinTime\BonusItems\Nyakuza Metro Bonus Item